# erro ao gerar o build do angular

Tags: angular

eu tenho um projeto angular que roda normalmente no ambiente de producao, mas estou querendo gerar o build dele e estou obtendo o seguinte erro ao usar o comando npm run build:

> ERROR in Error: Type ImageCropperComponent in C:/d/Workspaces/Curso
>   Java
>   Workspace/pk2-angular-v1.0.0/node_modules/ng2-img-cropper/src/imageCropperComponent.d.ts
>   is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in
>   C:/d/Workspaces/Curso Java
>   Workspace/pk2-angular-v1.0.0/src/app/app.module.ts and
>   ImageCropperModule in C:/d/Workspaces/Curso Java
>   Workspace/pk2-angular-v1.0.0/node_modules/ng2-img-cropper/src/imageCropperModule.d.ts!
>   Please consider moving ImageCropperComponent in C:/d/Workspaces/Curso
>   Java
>   Workspace/pk2-angular-v1.0.0/node_modules/ng2-img-cropper/src/imageCropperComponent.d.ts
>   to a higher module that imports AppModule in C:/d/Workspaces/Curso
>   Java Workspace/pk2-angular-v1.0.0/src/app/app.module.ts and
>   ImageCropperModule in C:/d/Workspaces/Curso Java
>   Workspace/pk2-angular-v1.0.0/node_modules/ng2-img-cropper/src/imageCropperModule.d.ts.
>   You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes
>   ImageCropperComponent in C:/d/Workspaces/Curso Java
>   Workspace/pk2-angular-v1.0.0/node_modules/ng2-img-cropper/src/imageCropperComponent.d.ts
>   then import that NgModule in AppModule in C:/d/Workspaces/Curso Java
>   Workspace/pk2-angular-v1.0.0/src/app/app.module.ts and
>   ImageCropperModule in C:/d/Workspaces/Curso Java
>   Workspace/pk2-angular-v1.0.0/node_modules/ng2-img-cropper/src/imageCropperModule.d.ts.

Ao ler o erro vi que esta lib que estou usando é parte de declaracao de dois modulos (não entendi oque que isso significa) mas vamos lá. no meu app.module que acusa o erro eu estou importando ele:

```
import { ImageCropperComponent } from 'ng2-img-cropper';
```

e declarei no meu declarations so @NgModule.
Alguem sabe me dizer como resolver?

Comment: Conssegui resolver, eu estava importando o component em declarations, mas o correto é importar o modulo em imports

Answer (score 0):

Você está declarando seu componente no 'declarations' (que são os componentes  e diretivas que pertencem a ele) ao invés do 'imports' (que são os que ele usa).